# Properties of exponential/logarithm

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I want to prove the following properties:

1. $\left (e^x\right )^y=e^{xy}$
2. $\ln (1)=0$
3. $\ln \left (x^y\right )=y\ln (x)$
4. $a^x\cdot a^y=a^{x+y}$ and $\frac{a^x}{a^y}=a^{x-y}$
5. $a^x\cdot b^x=\left (ab\right )^x$ and $\frac{a^x}{b^x}=\left (\frac{a}{b}\right )^x$
6. $\left (a^x\right )^y=a^{xy}$

I have done the following:

1. We have that $\displaystyle{\left (e^x\right )^y=e^{\ln \left (e^x\right )^y}=e^{y\cdot \ln e^x}=e^{y\cdot x}=e^{xy}}$

   We used the rule $\displaystyle{\log \left (x^a\right )=a\cdot \log x}$.
2. We have that $e^0=1$. We apply the logarithm and we get $\displaystyle{\ln \left (e^0\right )=\ln (1)\Rightarrow 0\cdot \ln (e)=\ln (1)\Rightarrow 0=\ln (1)}$.
3. We have that $e^{\ln x}=x$. We raise the equation to $n$ and we get $\left (e^{\ln x}\right )^y=x^y \Rightarrow e^{y\cdot \ln x}=x^y$. We take the logarithm of the equation and we get $\ln \left (e^{y\cdot \ln x}\right )=\ln \left (x^y\right ) \Rightarrow y\cdot \ln x=\ln \left (x^y\right )$.

   At 1. I used this rule, although I proved that here. Would there be also an other way to prove the property 1.?

Is everything correct so far?

Could you give me a hint for the remaining 3 properties? Do we use the previous properties?

Comment: A bit unusual because we usually start with the power rules and derive the logarithm-rules from it, but it seems OK. By the way, congratulations for reaching the 10k-rep-mark.

Comment: Thanks :-D $$$$ So the three first are correct, aren't they? Is the first one also correct although I used the property that I proved later? And what about thelast 3 properties? Do we hav to  write them in terms of a logarthm and the exponential function? @Peter

Comment: @Mary For $6$, take $\log_a$, it is similar to $1$

Comment: For 4. , you can use the other logarithm-rules.

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! I think it is clear now how to show the other 3 properties! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 4:

Let's say $a^x\cdot a^y = b$ for a number b. Taking the logarithms of both sides give : $\ln(a^x\cdot a^y) = \ln(b).$ Using the product rule for logarithms we get : $\ln(a^x) + \ln(a^y) = \ln(b)$ , and from the power rule we get : $(x+y)\cdot \ln(a) = \ln(b) $. Raising both sides to the e-th power give : $b = e^{(x+y)\cdot \ln(a)} = a^{x+y}$.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)